# Discord py, прочитать сообщение пользователя

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

суть такова.
Человек отправляет сообщение, к примеру "4". Затем бот записывает это значение в переменную, и далее спрашивает, ваша ставка? Далее ему пишут ставку, и опять же добавляет это значение в переменную.
Я написал такой код

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Казино'])
async def casino(message, member: discord.Member = None, amount:int = None):
    await message.send('Привет! Ну, что поиграем?. Какое число выпадет?(1-6)')
    time.sleep(10)
    ansver = message.content
    if re.match(r'[1-6]', ansver):
        await message.send('true')
```

Ошибка выдается, вроде -"content не содержится..."
Как мне получить это сообщение? Перепробовал много вариантов, ничего не помогло
Видел что реализуют через
@client_event
async def on_message, но тогда он будет на каждую цифру отвечать, а мне нужно чтобы запускался только через !Казино, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Постараюсь понятно объяснить. Для того, чтобы совершить ожидание, можете воспользоваться функцией `wait_for` и записать его в переменную, с которой потом можно делать то, что хочется.

Ниже привожу пример кода:

```py
msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda m: m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author.id == ctx.author.id)
await ctx.send('Ваше сообщение:', msg.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй уместить это в одну команду, типа "Казино 4" и если что проверку на значение сделать типа такой:

```py
    if type(x)==int && 0<x<=6:
        #other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, я вас правильно понял. Пользователь пишет команду со ставкой к примеру 1000:

**!Казино 1000**

Тогда это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
import re
from random import randint
from asyncio import TimeoutError

@client.command(aliases=["Казино"])
async def casino(ctx, amount: int):
    def check(m):
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id

    await ctx.send('Привет! Ну, что поиграем?. Какое число выпадет?(1-6)')

    try:
        # Ожидание ответа от пользователя. timeout - время ожидания.
        answer = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
        answer = answer.content
    except TimeoutError:
        # Если время ожидания вышло.
        return await ctx.send('Время вышло.')

    await ctx.send(f'Ваша ставка: {amount}')

    # Число от 1 до 6
    number = randint(1, 6)

    if re.match(r'[1-6]', answer):
        if number == int(answer):
            await ctx.send('Вы угадали!')
        else:
            return await ctx.send('Вы не угадали.')
    else:
        return await ctx.send('Нужно указать число!')
```

Прочитать про функцию **wait_for** можно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for).